# Runtime Error in Javascript code for google kick start question

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a google Kick Start question with Javascript but it keeps giving me a Runtime Error. I believe my code is correct syntax wise cause if I manually put all variable values, I get the right answers... Here is the question link : https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc7/00000000001d3f56

Here is my code :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const input = fs.readFileSync(0, 'utf8').trim().split('\n');

let currentline = 0;
function readline(){
    return input[currentline++];
}

let T = readline();
for (let i=0; i <= T; i++) {
    let [N, B] = readline(). split(' ');
    let arr = readline().split(' ');
    Console.log("Case #" + i + ": " + operation());
}

function operation() {
    var count = 0;
    arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b;});
    var total = 0;
    
    for (let i=0; total <= B; i++) {
    total += arr[i];
    count ++;
    }
    return count - 1;
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: How should this work with 0 as a file name?

Comment: 0 reads from the standard input(process.stdin), and the input is passed through stdin

Comment: Is there an actual error message?

Comment: `for (let i=0; i <= T; i++) {` <-- i is less than or equal to a string??

Comment: `for (let i=0; total <= B; i++) {` <-- B is not defined

Comment: `arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b;});` <-- arr is not defined

Comment: B, N and arr are defined by the readline() function though.. right? Also, T is an int not a string..

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the error message caused at runtime.